# How to make screen reader announce text when app is not active?

Tags: windows, qt, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I have an app that is running in the background not focused.

The user might be using some other applications, and based on certain events in my app, I want the screen reader to announce the text based on my liking.

I don't want my app to get the focus, user should be able to continue with the other application, I just want the screen reader to announce some texts.

I already tried sending `QAccessibleEvent` with different events like `Alert`, `NameChanged`, `ObjectShow`, etc...

But I think since my app is not in focus, it may not be passing through.

Could it be possible to achieve my requirement without my app getting focus?

I am using:

- Qt 5.15
- Windows 10

Comment: Wouldn’t that simply be a notification, that you can send to the desktop system?

Comment: @Andy Unfortunately its implemented as a QWidget and reworking that would require lot of efforts

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to directly call screen reader specific API.

However, if you are presenting some text on screen as well, you should rather preferably use the so called toasts, or the notification system, if it's suited to your application.
QT probably provides access to them.

Just in case, I'm the author of a DLL that allows to make several screen readers speak text.
Note that it doesn't show anything on screen.
http://github.com/qtnc/UniversalSpeech